# I have problem with import and export function using ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to import my function called funcoes.js at main.js and when I run this error appears:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

```
//funcoes.js
export function soma(a, b) {
    return a+b;
}

//main.js
import { soma } from './funcoes.js';

console.log(soma(1, 2));
```

Comment: What browser? Not all support ES6. It may be interpreting it as a function definition.

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome

Comment: Are you sure it's that line that generates the error? Looks fine.

Comment: Are you loading `main.js` as a module? (Do you have type="module" on your script tag?)

Comment: I tried but appears others problem

Comment: Could you post the error you receive when you use `type="module"`?

Comment: In your question, you don't mention how the modules are defined. Are you using plain HTML+JS in the browser? If that is the case, It uses type as other comments mention? Take a look to: https://v8.dev/features/modules

If you are using NodeJS modules are experimental and not enabled by default, if you are using Webpack to create a bundle you'll need to configure how to transform the code using Babel.

Comment: Access to script at 'file:///C:/Users/Vagner%20Wentz/Desktop/cursoes6/main.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
 GET file:///C:/Users/Vagner%20Wentz/Desktop/cursoes6/main.js net::ERR_FAILED
This is the error when I use type="module"

Comment: You cannot import from other `file://` URLs. You can start a local HTTP server however. Note that your "funcoes" file exports just the function, so the destructuring on the `import` does not make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot comment because Im new as well. Taking some other user's comments into consideration I was able to get your code to work with node's module.exports:

```
//funcoes.js
module.exports = {
soma(a, b) {
return a+b;
  }
}

//main.js
const {soma} = require ('./funcoes.js')
console.log(soma(1, 2))
```

Im making the sweeping assumption that you're trying to run this with node tho

Comment: I tried your code and appears 
> Uncaught ReferenceError: requires is not defined at main.js:2

Comment: The OP is trying to use standard JavaScript modules.